# Is it advised to sell current self occupied home and buy the other new one to book the profit?

Tags: india, real-estate, selling, home, second-mortgage

I have a first (and only) and self occupied home. Mortgage is fully paid. Home is with four rooms.

Considering expenses I done on home so far including my share in mortgage, taxes so far, total interest paid etc. I will be in profit by 1000000.

Prices of property are not growing considerably anymore; growth rate is minimized.

1. I do not need this much big home. Three rooms should be enough for me.
2. By booking the profit, I can invest the amount (other than my share in new home) in some good investments.
3. New home will be self-occupied as well; it will not be rented.

I can clearly see the benefit, but I am not sure about other financial aspects involved here.

1. New home will start new mortgage.
2. Taxes will not be much different.
3. As new home will be self occupied as well, there is no benefit other than the one gained while selling current home.

Is it advised to sell current self occupied home and buy the other new one to book the profit? If yes, what are the financial loop-holes to be considered while doing this?

I am not doing this for cash as asked [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/79211/73868). I am doing this for booking the profit.

Comment: Given that you apparently have another source of income to pay the mortgage on the second house, why not just take a (partial) mortgage on the first house and invest that?

Comment: Why is it necessary to have a mortgage on the new house when downsizing from one that is paid off? That's only the case if there is some aspect of the move that you'd like to finance rather than pay out of pocket; but that is your choice.

Comment: Have you considered keeping and renting out this house to help pay off the mortgage for the second one ?

Comment: @everyone: Yes; but that way, I cannot book the profit with my this house.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No one can answer this but yourself....

1) Have you considered closing cost (you'll pay the closing cost for at least 1 property if you sell yours and buy another.

2) Assuming you didn't spend a bunch of money on renovations it would seem that your profit comes mostly from the average home price rising. As such a 3 Bedroom house will also be far more expensive now than when you bought your house.

3) The cost of moving is not insignificant. You may also end up wanting to replace furniture. Some stuff always breaks during a move.

4) There are some other costs associated with moving that you may not have considered.

5) You may not end up getting as much money for your current house as you think you should. It also may not sell quickly.

For me personally all that would be too much hassle for what it's worth. But you may see things differently.

Comment: This answer ignores one major advantage of moving to a smaller home: A smaller home usually costs less to maintain in the long run (repairs, heating, etc.).

Comment: Point 2 -- or *effort*.  Even buying a house in a poor state of decoration and making it look nicer doing all the work yourself can be worth quite a lot on the sale price.  How you then value this time is another decision

Answer (score 6):

> I do not need this much big home. Three rooms should be enough for me.

This is the only real tick mark in favor of selling your current home.

> By booking the profit, I can invest the amount (other than my share in new home) in some good investments.

Any profit you make from the sell will either be taxed, or invested in the next home.  Is there a reason you wouldn't roll that over to the next house which would be tax advantaged?

Unless you have another reason like being closer to family, shorter commute, or always wanting to live in the city/on the coast/etc, I'd stay put.

**Moving always has one very big potential downside, neighbors for hell.**

Comment: That same downside is countered by the contrary: you may end up meeting great friends.

Comment: I am more with sevensevens, it is likely that you just say hello and goodbye with an nice neighbour and won't get friends ... But it is very likely that you notice the neighbour with the loud music, smelling food and the neighbour who is complaining about everything if they are close to you.

Comment: From personal experience.  I ended up selling and moving after 1 year because of harassment from a single neighbor.  It was cheaper to sell and move than to fight.

Answer (score 4):

If i understand you correctly you are thinkinh to move from a big home to a small one, this usually reducing your living cost (less things which could broke, less cleaning and less air to cool down/heat etc.)
Also you gain profit (or luxory) from the free and possible working money, from the price difference from the houses/appartments.
So if you don't need a big house, such a shift makes sense. Especially when you don't think that you miss the space of your current house much.

You want the mortage only, because you can think that you can outperform your credit rates with your investment? You could do this usually too, when you get a new mortage for your current house.

Answer (score 2):

There is no *profit* here, and there is no *investment*. It is your home and since everybody pays for the bed they sleep in, it is a cost, not an investment. If the house you are in has gone up in value, then so has the identical house next door and by the same amount, so moving from one to the other would not realize a return on an investment regardless of the change in the book value.

What you are proposing is a simple downsizing. This will release capital and (probably) reduce your operating costs, but the transaction has some predictable costs involved which will need to be deducted from the capital released. It may seem obvious, but if you can not finance the change without taking on debt, then the change is not worth it.